# How to pass List<String> from controller to <form:select> in Spring 4.0.0

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have an object with countryName attribute and method getCountryName() get all countryName from database by using below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT countryName from jobs
```

Now i want to pass this list into a form at jsp page as below:

```
<form:form>
<form:select>
<form:options> List of country name </form:options>
</form:select>
</form:form>
```

Anyone have ideas? I'm using Spring 4.0.0 REALEASE.

For easier understanding, i already had an annotation in my controller

```
@ModelAttribute("countries")
public List<String> getListCountryName(){
return dao.getCountryName() ;
```

}

How can i pass that list to view in spring's form tag?

Answer (score 1):

Write some thing like this:

```
 <form:form>
    <form:select path="commandAttribute">
          <form:option value="-" label="List of country namet"/>
          <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="countryName " itemLabel="countryName "/>
     </form:select>
    </form:form>
```

Reference http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/

Comment: Thanks bro, i've followed that tutorial, but it's not the same with my case. I want to write it in Spring 4 version.

Comment: I think it will do the same way. Because you are not precise. With Spring 3 or 4 is not the question, with thymeleaf rendering engine or with spring taglib - as answered - or with classical taglibs is the real question you are asking for.

Comment: Problem is i want to put this List in another <form:form> so it didn't work when i give a path value. The error i received is Spring can't find the commandProperty that i put it. Now it's was solved, thanks again guys!
@ThierryB : u're right Bro, i'm just a new comer in Spring Framework.